# Why is IntelliJ adding wrong maven dependency in my Spring Boot project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I click the import maven dependency in the pop up shown at RequestMapping, intellij adds

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>   
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But it should add this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve this? I have auto-import enabled for maven and I have tried both the maven bundled version with IntelliJ and the manually downloaded version.
Changing the dependency manually makes the program run correctly.

[image: Error in @RequestMapping]

Comment: It will find the dependency that contains that class. Which is `spring-web` and not the `spring-boot-starter-web` (as the latter is just a BOM containoing other dependencies).

Comment: Everything is ok. Spring Boot Starter dependencies are meant to be added manually or using start.spring.io.

Comment: @M.Deinum Where can I find more about them?

Answer (score 1):

Open `pom.xml`

Remove the below dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>   
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and add this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```